# Rename [skyrim] → [elder-scrolls-skyrim]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Because, you know, [scrolls](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/8519901309/bethesda-are-suing-us-heres-the-full-story) is a pretty important aspect of the game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a synonym is good enough. The Elder Scrolls games fall under the category of games which are often referred to by their sub-title (Skyrim, Oblivion, et cetera...), and so it is perfectly understandable what they mean.

Google trends also puts [*skyrim*](http://www.google.com/trends?q=skyrim) 10k searches ahead of [*elder scrolls skyrim*](http://www.google.com/trends?q=elder%20scrolls%20skyrim) or [*the elder scrolls skyrim*](http://www.google.com/trends?q=the%20elder%20scrolls%20skyrim).

Comment: Uh, well yeah - a less-restrictive search is *always* going have more hits than the same search but more restrictive...

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure a full renaming is in order, but I'll definitely put up a tag synonym between the two in the meantime.

I was originally leery about giving Skyrim this treatment, because it would necessitate renaming the rest of the elder scrolls tags.

That said, elder-scrolls-morrowind makes it in under the tag lenth (as does elder-scrolls-daggerfall), which I *think* are the longest names in the series, meaning that there shouldn't be an issue in doing all the rename requests you're suggesting.

Comment: What are we going to do with the [tag:the-elder-scrolls] tag then?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes, if we're going to append "elder-scrolls" to games in the series, then I think the series tag should be `elder-scrolls-series`, to be consistent with both the games and with other series tags. (As I mentioned when I [asked about the series earlier](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2591/8366), I don't feel that the series prefix is necessary, with the possible exception of Arena - should we ever get a question on it - but I can see it either way.)

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I'd assume it would become "the-elder-scrolls-series"

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Leave it as it is? We have plenty of series tags for other games.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis - holy crap. Ya beat me by 10 seconds. O.o And Fredley? 10 Seconds on the *other* side of me. What is this, everyone sandwich on Raven Dreamer? O.o

Comment: @Raven, haha! We're just practicing for Skyrim Week. (And this is a good thing to work out in advance.)