# Cleaning up the [star-wars] tag aka burning it with fire

Tags: discussion, tags

This tag is a mess. We've got games tagged [star-wars-empire-at-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-empire-at-war) with other *Empire At War* games not tagged with that tag, merely with [star-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars). We have *Knights of the Old Republic* tagged with [star-wars-kotor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-kotor) for the 1st game, yet for *Knights of the Old Republic 2*, it's tagged [kotor-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kotor-2). We've got the *Star Wars: The Force Unleashed* games tagged with only [force-unleashed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-unleashed) and the sequel improperly tagged with the first game.

We don't have any single question about any of [the](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_%281983_video_game%29) [three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_%28Namco_video_game%29) [games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_%28JVC_video_game%29) named only "Star Wars," so this tag should not exist.

**We should delete:**

- [star-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) - as stated, there aren't any questions about any of the games by this name

**I am Renaming:**

- [kotor-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kotor-2) to [star-wars-kotor-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-kotor-2) to be consistent with [star-wars-kotor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-kotor). [knights-of-the-old-republic-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-of-the-old-republic-2) itself blows past the limit, let alone [star-wars-knights-of-the-old-republic-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-knights-of-the-old-republic-2).

**I'm requesting Tag Synonyms for:**

- [kotor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kotor) -> [star-wars-kotor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-kotor) - It's a common enough abbreviation for the game that people are likely to try to use it
- [kotor-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kotor-2)/[kotor2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kotor2) -> [star-wars-kotor-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-kotor-2) Same thing
- [swtor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swtor) -> [star-wars-tor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-tor) The MMO is releasing next month, and we've already had a couple questions, so we should probably get this synonym in as well.

**I need tag suggestions for:**

- [Does it make a difference how many of the Emperor's bonus objectives you complete?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/does-it-make-a-difference-how-many-of-the-emperors-bonus-objectives-you-complet) This question. I don't know enough about the game to tell if the user is only asking about *[Star Wars: TIE Fighter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_TIE_Fighter)* or the game *[Star Wars: X-Wing vs. TIE Fighter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_X-Wing_vs._TIE_Fighter)*. As far as I can tell, the user's only making a superficial comparison in gameplay to the *Star Wars: X-Wing* game (both games are part of the [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Wing_computer_game_series)), in which case the tag should probably be [star-wars-tie-fighter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-tie-fighter) (which should have [tie-fighter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tie-fighter) as a synonym).
- The questions about *Star Wars: The Force Unleashed* and its sequel. [star-wars-the-force-unleashed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-the-force-unleashed) again blows past the tag limit. I would suggest [sw-the-force-unleashed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-the-force-unleashed) as a substitute to keep consistency with having the series name like the other games, but I'm not sure.

---

In regards to keeping the series name at all, I just want to mention I'm following the precedent we've set with the [Prince of Persia series](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/how-should-we-tag-prince-of-persia), the [Need for Speed series](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-to-tag-the-need-for-speed-games), the [Kingdom Hearts series](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3289/how-should-we-tag-kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep), and the [five](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed) [different](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-2) [Assassin's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-pl) [Creed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-bh) [tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-revel) we have.

Comment: `[star-wars-force-unleashed]` comes in at 25 chars exactly. I think it would be better to keep the `[star-wars]` series name consistent.

Comment: don't forget [swtor] vs [star-wars-the-old-republic], before that gets out of hand too.

Comment: @Yi What about its sequel then? `[star-wars-force-unleashed-2]` doesn't fit. :(

Comment: @David I'll add a synonym request for that as well. We have `[star-wars-tor]` for that because `[star-wars-the-old-republic]` is again **26** letters. Argh.

Comment: Hm, the fact there are three games with the same name kind of worries me... I hope they're at least for unique platforms?

Comment: The tag problems! They never stop! Burninate ALL the tags!

Comment: @badp They're an arcade game, a Famicom game, and a NES game. I'm assuming we won't get any questions on them, but let's cross that bridge when we come to it. :P

Comment: I think that [sw-the-force-unleashed-2] would work - I've honestly never heard of any of them actually verbally referred to as as anything other than "Force Unleashed" and "Force Unleashed 2" - it's rare that people (in my experience) say the whole thing.

Comment: Burn this tag like Anakin got burned by the lava...that crybaby.

Comment: +1. Fire is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

The TIE Fighter question pertains to **TIE Fighter** and NOT **X-Wing vs TIE Fighter**.  It has nothing to do with X-Wing, as you noted.

Comment: Thank you! I've never played any of those games, so I wanted to double check.

Answer (score 4):

I thought that we were getting away from using the series name in the tag except when absolutely necessary [due to better SEO](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/rename-skyrim-elder-scrolls-skyrim).  As such I'd go with the following which you'll note are all unambiguous:

- [the-old-republic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-old-republic) with [swtor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swtor) and [tor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tor) as synonyms
- [kotor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kotor) with *possibly* [knights-of-tor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-of-tor) as a synonym
- [kotor-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kotor-2) with [the-sith-lords](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sith-lords) and *possibly* [knights-of-tor-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-of-tor-2) as synonyms
- [force-unleashed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-unleashed)
- [force-unleashed-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-unleashed-2)
- [empire-at-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empire-at-war)
- [tie-fighter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tie-fighter)
- [x-wing-vs-tie-fighter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-wing-vs-tie-fighter)

As Ashley noted, most of the time people don't bother writing "Star Wars" and you'd think that when searching for a tag they *definitely* wouldn't bother since it will obviously not be unique. So I think the above will work just fine.  [star-wars-acronym](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-acronym) seems much less clear to me than [full-name](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/full-name) anyways.

Plus all others I can think of if we have or get questions:

- [the-phantom-menace](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-phantom-menace) with [star-wars-episode-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-episode-1) as a synonym
- [the-clone-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-clone-wars) with [star-wars-episode-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-episode-2) as a synonym
- [revenge-of-the-sith](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revenge-of-the-sith) with [star-wars-episode-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-episode-3) as a synonym
- [episode-1-racer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/episode-1-racer) with [podracer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podracer) as a synonym
- [racer-revenge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racer-revenge) with [podracer-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/podracer-2) as a synonym
- [rebel-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebel-assault)
- [rebel-assault-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebel-assault-2) with [the-hidden-empire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hidden-empire) as a synonym
- [battle-for-naboo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battle-for-naboo)
- [dark-forces](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-forces)
- [jedi-knight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-knight) with [dark-forces-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-forces-2) and [mysteries-of-the-sith](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysteries-of-the-sith) (unless it warrants its own tag) as synonyms
- [jedi-outcast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-outcast) with [jedi-knight-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-knight-2) as a synonym
- [jedi-academy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-academy) with [jedi-knight-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-knight-3) as a synonym
- [force-commander](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-commander)
- [galaxies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galaxies)
- [imperial-commando](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperial-commando)
- [republic-commando](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republic-commando)
- [rebellion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebellion)
- [battlefront](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefront)
- [battlefront-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefront-2)
- [renegade-squadron](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renegade-squadron) with [battlefront-renegade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefront-renegade) as a synonym
- [elite-squadron](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elite-squadron) with [battlefront-elite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefront-elite) as a synonym
- [shadows-of-the-empire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadows-of-the-empire)
- [rogue-squadron](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-squadron)
- [rogue-leader](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-leader) with [rogue-squadron-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-squadron-2) as a synonym
- [rebel-strike](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebel-strike) with [rogue-squadron-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-squadron-3) as a synonym
- etc.

Yes, I have played too many Star Wars games.

Comment: *"with [episode-1] as a synonym..."* **NO! NO! NO! NO!** Please think about all of the other episodic games!!!

Comment: How well does this strategy hold up when Super Mario Galaxies is released?

Comment: @Matt so you'd prefer a system which uses less specific tags until there is a need to disambiguate and then goes in and changes the tagging scheme as necessary?  How do we keep track if it is necessary, and which to pre-pend to?

Comment: @Matt perhaps a system which minimizes potential confusion and/or retagging?

Comment: @Matthew As I stated, I was following the precedent that we've set for many other series here. Perhaps this necessitates a new meta thread regarding what we should do about series names in game title tagging.

Comment: @MatthewRead which of the following minimizes confusion and retagging (change over time): [galaxies], [sw-galaxies], or [star-wars-galaxies]?  How about [star-wars-rs2] vs [rogue-leader]?  Which is more likely to hash to two different games and cause misuse?

Comment: @Matt I'm not trying to annoy you, I'm trying to express an idea.  You said minimizing confusion and retagging was your intention; yet you go on to express that you think [rogue-leader] exemplified this characteristics.  Clearly this is something I'm missing here.  Rogue-leader isn't a unique hash to begin with.  It collides with a book as well as a canonical character and a title.  Perhaps there is something else you're optimizing for that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Matt ignoring the discussion of whether or not cannon is allowable on this site, can you really say there will never be another game called Rogue Leader?  Seems like a pretty bold statement.  Now, I'd say odds are low, but they're lower still for Star-Wars-Rogue-Leader.

Comment: @Matt the cost of changing a tag down the line is non-trivial.  There will be people who use the old tag for the second game and have to deal with the synonym constantly changing.  This is especially egregiousness for new users to the site, who won't understand why [rogue-leader] (the hot new iphone game) keeps coming out [star-wars-rogue-leader].  Still others new users might downvote the clearly mistagged question, and multiple edits (as people try to fix it) might overwrite other necessary changes.

Comment: What's more it only takes one.  Mario Galaxies comes out and we have [star-wars-galaxies] and [rogue-leader] (a clear inconsistency).  People open up threads on meta and we go through this discussion yet again.  Wouldn't it seem to be prudent to short circuit this whole process?

Comment: @Matt *"I don't think it's grounded in any sort of reality*"? That two games would have similar abbreviations? [Alien-Breed-3-Descent] and [Descent-3]? [Battle-Field-Vietnam], [Men-of-War-Vietnam], [Conflict-Vietnam] and [Magicka-Vietnam]? [BlackSite-Area-51] and [Area 51]?  You can tell I didn't have to get very far in the alphabet to start finding overloaded terms.  Worse still, in some cases the abbreviation was the name of another game.  I'm not saying this is the end of the world, but I would err on the side of a consistent customer experience

Comment: citation: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html